# fetch(url, {method:HEAD}) gives CORS error only if file doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, cors, fetch

I need to check if a list of files is present on a server. When running this code

```
const promises = sentences.map(sentence => {
        return fetch(`https://.../${sentence.id}.mp3`, {
            method: 'HEAD',
            cache: 'no-store',
        })
    })

    const responses = await Promise.all(promises)

    const notFound = responses.filter(response => !response.ok)
```

And having set the `.htaccess` file in the directory to

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET "
```

The response status for a file that exists is 200, but for the files that doesn't exist there's still the CORS error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` which prevents the function to finish.

Is this due to the 404 *"Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server."* redirection? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET "
> ```

To set these headers on non-200 responses (ie. 404s), you need to use the `always` condition. For example:

```
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET "
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header